# Error 503 Backend fetch failed Guru Meditation: XID: 45654 Varnish cache server in magento2

Tags: varnish

we are using MAgento 2.1 and elastic suite ,rediss cache and varnish cache 4

so we have 60 K products in our site and recently we updated attribute in magento2 admin from that day onwords we are getting error like

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed
Guru Meditation:
XID: 45654
Varnish cache server
```

so we updated varnish config with below :

```
-p http_resp_hdr_len=65536 \
-p http_resp_size=98304 \
```

but the error is the same. How can we fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that Varnish can't get a HTTP response from your backend; specifically it's having trouble connecting to your backend webserver, nginx or apache.

Can you copy your varnish default.vcl file?